# iOS: UIAlertView closes current popover

Tags: ios

I currently have a view that is in a popover above the main scene. When the user pressed a button, the new scene pops up in a popover and they are able to press different buttons. When a certain button is pressed, I call a `UIAlertView`. When the `UIAlertView` is called, it goes back to the main `UIViewController` and dismisses the popover.

How can I prevent this from happening? The desired behavior would be for the `UIAlertView` to disappear and leave the popover in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it was behaving this way. I had a segue set up on button via Storyboard. I also had the `UIAlertView` pop up programmatically from the same button. When the user pressed the button, the segue would dimiss the popover back to the main `UIViewController` and the `UIAlertView` would pop up. I removed the segue and everything seems to be fine.